# Sub-resource locators in Kotlin/Dropwizard

Tags: jersey, kotlin, dropwizard

I'm trying to implement a resource with a subresource in Dropwizard 1.0 utilizing Kotlin 1.0.3. I have a sample resource:

```
package net.reznik.stackoverflow.resources

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes
import javax.ws.rs.Path
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam
import javax.ws.rs.Produces
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType

@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
class TestResource {

    @Path("/{foo}/")
    fun subresource(@PathParam("foo") foo: String): Any {
        return TestSubResource()
    }
}
```

And a subresource:

```
package net.reznik.stackoverflow.resources

import javax.ws.rs.POST
import javax.ws.rs.Path
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response

class TestSubResource {

    @POST
    @Path("/bar")
    fun bar(request: String): Response {
        return Response.ok("entity received: $request", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE).build()
    }
}
```

If I change the return type of the subresource function from `Any` to `TestSubResource`, then everything works as expected. I'd like to use `Any` as the return type so that I can return different sub-resources depending on the value of `{foo}`.

When using `Any`, dropwizard blows up on start up with a long stacktrace...

```
WARN  [2016-08-31 22:01:32,454] /: unavailable
! java.lang.NullPointerException: null
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.DropwizardResourceConfig$EndpointLogger.populate(DropwizardResourceConfig.java:173)
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.DropwizardResourceConfig$EndpointLogger.populate(DropwizardResourceConfig.java:164)
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.DropwizardResourceConfig$EndpointLogger.populate(DropwizardResourceConfig.java:189)
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.DropwizardResourceConfig$EndpointLogger.populate(DropwizardResourceConfig.java:164)
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.DropwizardResourceConfig$EndpointLogger.populate(DropwizardResourceConfig.java:159)
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.DropwizardResourceConfig.getEndpointsInfo(DropwizardResourceConfig.java:130)
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.DropwizardResourceConfig.logComponents(DropwizardResourceConfig.java:80)
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.DropwizardResourceConfig$ComponentLoggingListener.onEvent(DropwizardResourceConfig.java:245)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.monitoring.CompositeApplicationEventListener.onEvent(CompositeApplicationEventListener.java:74)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:629)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
! at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:640)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:419)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:875)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:349)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:106)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
! at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.doStart(InstrumentedHandler.java:103)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:106)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.doStart(GzipHandler.java:231)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:106)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:106)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.doStart(StatisticsHandler.java:252)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:411)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:106)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:378)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
! at io.dropwizard.cli.ServerCommand.run(ServerCommand.java:53)
! at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:44)
! at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:85)
! at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:75)
! at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:79)
```

Is there a way to implement subresource locator with kotlin/dropwizard such that I can dynamically return one of several subresources based on my own custom logic - i.e., use a return type of `Any`?

Comment: I'm familiar with Jersey, JAX-RS 2.0, and Kotlin but I have no experience with Dropwizard. How similar are your sub-resources? Could they implement a common interface and then you could use that instead of `Any`?

Comment: I did try that approach as well, but get the same error. Also tried extending from java.lang.Object, as bad as that seems, but had the same issue.

Comment: It is possible that Dropwizard does not support the polymorphic subresources, it appears to be building only a static model of the resource tree.  Or this is another bug with Any/Object as a return type.  Actually your error is during logging of endpoints, there were issues with subresource logging so maybe that didn't take into account the Any/Object case because it is done at Serlvet Init when the type isn't known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Jersey works with Polymorphic resources returning a type that is also possible a resource, it resolves this sub-resource at runtime during the request.  DropWizard uses Jersey pretty much as-is and therefore would support this use-case.

But, DropWizard has a feature to log the output of the routing bindings being made, where it outputs the resource configuration it has determined during Servlet init.  And this code has a bug.  I reported the exact bug here:

https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/1716

I do not see an easy work around such as turning this logging call off nor deregistering the event.  It appears a patch needs to be made to DropWizard.

**UPDATE:** this issue has been resolved by pull request https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/pull/1718 and if you track the next release using that merge into `master` it will include this fix.

Comment: Thanks for reporting the bug directly to dropwizard - that was a quick bugfix!